# How to automatically watch for file changes and perform a custom action inside shell?

Tags: command-line

For example, I'd like to automatically run [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) whenever I edit a JavaScript source file to output a compressed version.

Ideally the process does not run in the background but in a dedicated shell, so I can easily terminate the process at the end of the day.

What would be the cleanest and most flexible way to watch specific files and/or directories for file changes and perform a custom action inside a shell?

Answer (score 2):

The $25 [Codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) does watch folders and files for changes and does compress/minify/combine JavaScript and CSS files.

I know this is only a partial answer for your question, as it is not a generic watcher, but it does fit your example:

> whenever I edit a JavaScript source file to output a compressed
>   version

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a handy app, but it's not exactly the solution I was looking for. I'd really like something generic that can watch files and perform any custom command on changes.

Answer (score 1):

Watching a file for changes can be accomplished with a LaunchAgent. For example create a plist file at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/watch.and.lol.plist` and fill it with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>watch.and.lol</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/Shared/changeAction.sh</string>
        <string>-force</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/private/var/radmind/client/.radmindOnDemand</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now make sure that the file `/private/var/radmind/client/.radmindOnDemand` does exist. Then load the launchagent with command `$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/watch.and.lol.plist`. As soon as the file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/watch.and.lol.plist` does no longer exist, this launchagent job will be unloaded.

Now write some shell script that watches your file for changes, like:

```
chsum1=""

while [[ true ]]
do
    chsum2=`md5 /private/var/radmind/client/.radmindOnDemand`
    if [[ $chsum1 != $chsum2 ]] ; then           
        compile
        chsum1=`md5 /private/var/radmind/client/.radmindOnDemand`
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

Note: this shell script needs some extra work to be done to make it efficient. Now it polls every 2 seconds (`sleep 2`). Better is to exit the script after the `compile` command has executed. That requires the storage of the output of the md5 hash command that can survive the exit and relauch of this shell script.

Comment: Thank you. I don't really fancy writing a launch agent everytime though, I'm looking for a solution flexible enough to add watchers and specify the file to watch and the command to run as an argument on the fly.